# print a sequence type of numbers .starting to ending

Tags: python-3.x

Here the input is in the sequence `AA01AA0001A` it should print all the combinations i.e,from `AA01AA0001A` to `ZZ99ZZ9999Z` 
for example:

```
INPUT ='AA 01 AA 0001 A
OUTPUT ='AA 01 AA 0001 A
--------------

----------------
'ZZ 99 ZZ 9999 Z'
```

I have tried to solve the code but did't get the output any one can give suggestions to solve  the problem. Here is the below code which I

```py
import string
a_list = string.ascii_uppercase
input = 'AB 01 AB 0001 A'
output = 'ZZ 99 ZZ 9999 Z'
for Outer_index,a_zouter in enumerate(a_list):
    for inner_index,a_zinner in enumerate(a_list):
        print(f"{a_zouter}{a_zinner} {str(Outer_index + inner_index + 1).rjust(2,'0'){a_zinner}{a_zouter} {str(outer_index + inner_index + 1)_.rjust(4,'0')}{a_zinner}")
```

Comment: can u solve this one. i can't get the answer

Comment: INPUT ='AA 01 AA 0001 A
OUTPUT ='AA 01 AA 0001 A
                  'AB 02 AB 0002 B
                  AC 03 AC 0003 C
                   ----------------------
                  'ZZ 99 ZZ 9999 Z'

Comment: those are `1.188138e+13` permutations. Are you sure you want to print all those? What is the purpose??

Comment: yes  bro i want to print all sequence order

Comment: Why do you need all those? that is more than 1 trillion!!! You either need a very very large machine or you can print a few